# Removing white spaces and zooming the each image proportionately using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my task
[image: Removing white spaces and zooming the each image proportionately]

in the above image, I drag and drop each image from right side container to left container and i also provide resizing,rotating,flip/flop,forward/backward etc for image. Each image having specific with,height top and left,and we can drag any no of images.

After completion of drag and drop I need to publishing these items, now here is my task is in above sample image I dropped 2 images.here red line is need to remove empty spaces and zoom each image proportionately.

Finally i want Output like this
[image: Output]

please help me

Thanks in advance